# I don't think the code is right in c programming language

Tags: c

I am learning C programming language from https://www.learn-c.org/. In the Conditions section, there is an exercise which I am writing below-

In this exercise, you must construct an `if` statement inside the `guessNumber` function statement that checks if the number guess is equal to 555. If that is the case, the function must print out using `printf()` the message `Correct. You guessed it!`. If guess is less than 555, the function must print out using `printf()` `Your guess is too low.`, and if guess is greater than 555, the function must print out using `printf()` `Your guess is too high.`

The thing is I don't think the output is correct. I just want to clear the doubt. Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    guessNumber(500);
    guessNumber(600);
    guessNumber(555);
}

void guessNumber(int guess) {
    if (guess < 555) {
        printf("Your guess is too low.\n");
    } else if (guess > 555) {
        printf("Your guess is too high.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Correct. You guessed it!\n");
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Your guess is too low.  
Your guess is too high.  
Correct. You guessed it!
```

Comment: What makes you think that the output is incorrect? What output would you expect to consider it correct?

Comment: What else do you expect to see as your output then?

Comment: Apart from the lack of clarity why you think the output incorrect, I do not even really see what your question is. Or to put it differently, what kind of answer do you expect.  I have a hunch that none of the following would satisfy you "It is correct.", "You are right, it is incorrect." So what would help you? "It is incorrect, bacause ....", "It is correct because...", "Change the code like this ... to make the output correct." What are you looking for?

Comment: The problem is the program is not asking me to guess any number.

Comment: "the program is not asking me to guess any number" (1) how do you want it to ask you if you have not programmed in any asking? (2) why do you want it to ask you when the problem statements says absolutely nothing whatsoever about asking?

Answer (score 2):

The program is demonstrating how the `guessNumber` function might validate guesses.  But it is not actually prompting a human user to make any guesses.

To do that, you could write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int guessNumber(int guess) {

    if (guess < 555) {
        printf("Your guess is too low.\n");
        return 0;
    } else if (guess > 555) {
        printf("Your guess is too high.\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Correct. You guessed it!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int guess;
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter your guess: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        if (scanf("%d", &guess) != 1)
            break;
        if (guessNumber(guess))
            break;
        printf("Try again.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prompts the user to enter a number, calls `guessNumber` to validate it, and if the guess isn't right, repeats the process.  So that the loop in `main` knows whether to continue, I changed `guessNumber` to return an `int` -- true (1) if the user guessed it, false (0) otherwise.

This ends up being kind of a weird program.  It's important, but somewhat of an art, to divide a program usefully into functions.  Here, the `guessNumber` function checks the answer and prints a result, but it doesn't do the prompting.  And we can tell that the final program doesn't have the parts divided quite right because we had to introduce an extra little data path -- the `int` return I added -- to let the two parts of the program communicate with each other and coordinate their activities.

(Also, of course, in a real program the number to be guessed wouldn't be hardwired inside of `guessNumber` like that.  It would probably be passed in as an argument, or something.)

But with those quibbles aside, there's another useful lesson lurking here which is that oftentimes, when you've written a new function, and the main program that will use it isn't ready yet, it's useful to write a completely different, small, `main` program just to test your new function out.

In fact, when you've written a new function, it's often a good idea to write a small, `main` program just to test your new function out, no matter what.  Your small, simple `main` program can make sure that your function works on all its test cases, and now you *know*.  If the first thing you do with with your new function is integrate it in with the big, complicated main program that will use it, there are two problems that come up:

1. Maybe the big, complicated main program didn't quite put your function through quite all its paces -- maybe it doesn't happen to call it for one case, and maybe that's the case that has a bug you don't know about yet.
2. If the big, complicated main program calls your function and something goes wrong, indicating a bug, is the bug in your function or in the big, complicated main program?  Sometimes its hard to know.

So that's why the small, simple `main` program  -- the technical term for this is "[test harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness)" -- just to test your function is often a good idea.

Comment: Using `fflush(stdout)` is good practice. Normally it is omitted when taking input relying on the implementation to conform with [C11 Standard - 7.21.3 Files(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p3)